No wifi adapter found, dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11
My laptop is an MSI Katana 15 B12V. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows 11, but the wifi adapter is not found. The wifi can be turned on, but no networks are found.

I tried disabling fast startup in Window, and made sure that windows is shut down properly.
The network device is detected as shown by the output of lspci | grep -i network:
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)

And for the drivers, I checked using lspci -k | grep -iA2 network:
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wi-Fi 6(802.11ax) AX201 160MHz 2x2 [Harrison Peak]

I also checked if it is hard blocked bu running rfkill list, I got
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo lshw -C network command returned:
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: d4:e9:8a:d8:85:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-51-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:6205234000-6205237fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: d8:43:ae:09:48:cc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-51-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:79204000-79204fff memory:79200000-79203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 15
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: enxcecfef6436e3
       serial: ce:cf:ef:64:36:e3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-51-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.77.9 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

I do not exactly know the meaning of DISABLED but I believe this is the problem
this is the output of sudo dmesg | grep firmware
[  748.615033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  748.807970] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  748.997713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  749.186987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  759.204916] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  759.403898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  759.604555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  759.799120] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  759.991653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  760.188244] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  770.197019] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  770.399238] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  770.600375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  770.804418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  771.007280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  771.202898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  781.199405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  781.406802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  781.609732] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  781.814982] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  782.023162] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  782.229614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[  796.321596] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[  923.128980] audit: type=1400 audit(1735572234.464:199): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache_systemd_detect_virt" name="/sys/firmware/dmi/entries/0-0/raw" pid=6689 comm="systemd-detect-" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  993.080384] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[  993.118104] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1188.706210] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1190.236459] audit: type=1400 audit(1735572501.567:358): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.firmware-updater.hook.configure" pid=15292 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1194.270373] audit: type=1400 audit(1735572505.601:383): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" pid=15679 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1239.265543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1239.473845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1239.681580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1239.884074] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1240.089044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1240.299777] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
[ 1460.495294] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1460.495658] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1460.534020] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1496.380091] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)
[ 1718.084909] ACPI Warning: Time parameter 250 us > 100 us violating ACPI spec, please fix the firmware. (20230628/exsystem-141)

I updated my BIOS to the latest version (E1585IMS.317) yesterday before installing Ubuntu.
Secure Boot and Fast Boot are both disabled.

Not sure what is happening but what result from terminal for rfkill list; sudo dmesg | grep iwl

@Jeremy31 Thank you for replying, I solved the problem today by downgrading the bios version, once I booted up windows and used for for some time it was lagging a lot, it looked like the nvidia drivers were the problem but after trying several versions I decided to downgrade the bios and it solved both problems

the problem was solved by downgrading the bios, in case anyone with the same problem and the same configuration comes across this question, here are the links I used:
MSI Katana 15 B12VGK with Nvidia RTX 4070
Link for bios files
this link will result in a not found page, just edit the version number at the end before .zip for example https://download-2.msi.com/bos_exe/nb/E1585IMS.317.zip to download the 317 version
until the moment of writing this, version 311 is working fine for me
